# Google Map with markers.

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, maps

I have recently integrated WordPress into a clients website.

On the current contact page they have a Google Map with a marker. I have copied and pasted the code over to the new website and have created a new API key.

However on the new website, the map is a static map without markers.

The new website is:
http://www.wrightandcobrighton.co.uk/contact

The old website with correct working map: http://www.wrightandcobrighton.co.uk/old/contact.html

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Please include your code in the post, not just links to pages that will change and go away eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a jQuery conflict.

```
TypeError: $ is not a function $("#location").prepend('<div id="map"></div>');
```

—

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("#location").prepend('<div id="map"></div>');
});
```

Worked.

I'll make sure I use pastebin in the future. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a JavaScript error to do with Nivo Slider. Try commenting out or fixing your Nivo Slider JavaScript between lines `33` and `44`. This error may be stopping the Google Maps code executing.